# 'C/C++' category completely missing from project property dialog in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

[image: GONE]

As you can see from the picture above, there is no c/c++ option. I'm completed stumped as to where it has gone. I've seen screenshots from earlier versions of VS (specifically 2015 and 2010). This is from a fresh install a VS with some addon packages. If the specific version is needed I will provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and the reason was that I had removed all C++ files from the project. Adding them again resulted in the C++ section reappearing.
Thanks.